# Openapi - duplicate operationID and extra parameter

Tags: django-rest-framework, swagger, schema, documentation, openapi

I'm documenting my Django API using Swagger.When I generate my Openapi schema, a second route with an additional parameter `{format}` is added for each of my paths, with the same operation ID as the "correct" route.

I read that the generator may generate duplicate operationId if I have several views with the same model, but this is not my case I think.

Overall, my views (resource/api/views.py) are all organized like this:

```
class ResourceList(APIView):

    """
    View to list Resources.
    """

    def get(self, request, parameter1):
       ...

class ResourceDetail(APIView):

    """
    View to retrieve information of a Resource.
    """

    def get(self, request, parameter1, parameter2):
        ...
```

For these two views, I have these two paths:

```
urlpatterns = ([
    path('<str:parameter1>', views.ResourceList.as_view()),
    path('<str:parameter1>/details/<str:parameter2>', views.ResourceDetail.as_view())
])
```

And the schema generator generates two routes for each.

For the first path:

```
Route: /api/resource/{parameter1}, Method: get
Route: /api/resource/{parameter1}{format}, Method: get
```

For the second path:

```
Route: /api/resource/{parameter1}/details/{parameter2}, Method: get
Route: /api/resource/{parameter1}/details/{parameter2}{format}, Method: get
```

A warning like this appears:

```
Route: /api/resource/{parameter1}, Method: get
Route: /api/resource/{parameter1}{format}, Method: get
An operationId has to be unique across your schema. Your schema may not work in other tools.
```

The warning obviously makes sense, because both routes have the same operationID,(`retrieveResourceList` in this case). What I don't understand is why the second route is being generated and where that `format` parameter comes from.

Is this a normal behaviour? If not, what am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might not be the way to resolve this fully but in my case, I try commenting the `format_suffix_patterns` and the `format` parameter disappear. Here is how I manage the urls:

```
from rest_framework.urlpatterns import format_suffix_patterns

urlpatterns = [...]

urlpatterns = format_suffix_patterns(urlpatterns) # Comment this
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm using Autoschema to overide operation_id

```
from rest_framework.schemas.openapi import AutoSchema
class CandidateAssignToMeList(CandidateMixins,generics.ListAPIView):
    schema = AutoSchema(
        tags=['LISTVIEW'],
        component_name='Assign To Me',
        operation_id_base='CandidateAssignToMeList',
    )
class CandidateList(CandidateMixins,generics.ListAPIView):
     schema = AutoSchema(
        tags=['LISTVIEW'],
        component_name='Candidate ListView',
        operation_id_base='CandidateList',
    )
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this is applicable in your specific case - seems AutoSchema might get unique OperationIDs anyways, but...

You may always manually specify the operation_id_base which is used to generate all the operation identifiers.  This prevents the issue where you have overlapping operationIds and the corresponding errors:

```
from rest_framework.schemas.openapi import AutoSchema    
class ResourceDetail(APIView):

    """
    View to retrieve information of a Resource.
    """
    schema = AutoSchema(operaton_id_base='resource_detail')
    def get(self, request, parameter1, parameter2):
        ...
```